# android mkdirs returns false

Tags: android, mkdir

I've been using the following code to successfully create folders, however on a samsung tab2 Android 4.2.2 (pre kitkat new security) the command returns false even though the new folder does not exist

newfolder is a string variable that comes from a folder choosing dialog, for example the user selects "/mnt/extSdcard" in the dialog and we append "/myfolder" making:
"/mnt/extSdcard/myfolder"
and we have also tried
"/storage/extSdcard/myfolder"

```
try {
    File sd = new File(newfolder);
    if(!sd.exists() || !sd.isDirectory()) {
        allisgood = sd.mkdirs();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
```

allisgood returns false even though myfolder does not exist under /storage/extSdcard or /mnt/extSdcard

Android permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any thought as to why mkdirs fails and what can be done to make it work.

Note we cannot use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as this returns
emulated/0
which is the internal non removable sdcard on this device, apart from that we want the user to be able to choose the location of myfolder using the folder picking dialog and that can be internal or removable sdcard.

Comment: Can you try this  `/mnt/extSdcard/myfolder/`   (slash at end)

Comment: Also you can get External SD card like this   `final String rawExternalStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    // All Secondary SD-CARDs (all exclude primary) separated by ":"
    final String rawSecondaryStoragesStr = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    // Primary emulated SD-CARD
    final String rawEmulatedStorageTarget = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET");`

Comment: I appended the slash /mnt/extSdcard/myfolder/ but the File command removes it or rather does not display it and I still get false from mkdirs

Comment: thanks simpleguy, when I compared rawSecondaryStoragesStr with my string path it became obvious it was a case issue. I was setting my path to all lowercase. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Oh heck, further up in the code I was setting the folder path selected by the user in my dialog to lowercase. And as we all know Android/Unix is case sensitive which means extsdcard does not exist! Ahhhhhh! Sorry